# Missing button icons from certain applications - Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: debian, ubuntu, lubuntu

I have a problem where when I open certain applications some of the icons are missing. For example in gedit, some of the button icons are missing as shown below.

[image]

I installed `gnome-icon-theme` and that fixed the X button but now I don't know where to go from here.

What package should I install? What would fix this issue?

Machine OS: Lubuntu 20.04

Machine Specs: Virtual Box Guest with 8G of RAM, 6 Threads of AMD Ryzen 5 3600X and 128G of Video Memory

Comment: Did you do anything immediately prior to this problem that might have caused this?

Comment: No. This is a clean install of Lubuntu

Comment: Can you edit your question to include basic details of RAM / disk space / CPU as Lubuntu is described as "perfect for low-end hardware and lightweight systems", although I appreciate this is not a solution for your icon problem. If you have more than minimal hardware, there are a number of distros that may suit you better.

Comment: added machine specs. Does it matter if it is a virtual machine

Comment: VM's are fine - but you could run any Linux in 8GB. Not clear why you chose Lubuntu though.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the icon pack you are using..  it may be custom icon that you have placed in .icon folder. To solve this you have to paste the icon pack in /usr/share/icon folder to remove this problem.. :)